# Call URL from SSH

Tags: php, ssh

I have a PHP page that transfers data from one database to another database when its called.

For example when I call `mydomain.com/transfer` then the transfer starts.

I don't want to use a cron job for this. Instead I am running this URL on browsers and I will get an php echo message that 5000 records are transferred. I need to run this link for almost 50 times to transfer large number of records from one database to another database.

I am just wondering is there any SSH command to call the URL `mydomain.com/transfer` so that it will complete the transfer process and displays the echo message?

Thanks

Comment: curl or wget are both candidates

Comment: @RC - I believe they are to download files, when if I try to wget it just tries to download a webpage, how can it execute PHP code?

Comment: @Kerry "Opening" a webpage is essentially "downloading" the webpage (and render).

Answer (score 0):

`Wget` and `curl` will "`run`" the php file as if you were in the browser and then download the HTML result.

`$ php path/file.php`

will run a local php file and `echo` on the run.

Because of security issues (and by design) you can't use this via `http`.